# intel_gpu_top crashes on 16.04

Tags: intel-graphics

When I run `intel_gpu_top` on my 16.04 system, it crashes at line 145 in `intel_mmio.c`:

```
~$ intel_gpu_top
(intel_gpu_top:25862) intel-mmio-CRITICAL: Test assertion failure function intel_mmio_use_pci_bar, file ../../lib/intel_mmio.c:145:
(intel_gpu_top:25862) intel-mmio-CRITICAL: Failed assertion: !(error != 0)
(intel_gpu_top:25862) intel-mmio-CRITICAL: Last errno: 13, Permission denied
(intel_gpu_top:25862) intel-mmio-CRITICAL: Couldn't map MMIO region
Stack trace:
  #0 [_init+0x83d9]
  #1 [_init+0x6036]
  #2 [_init+0x1301]
  #3 [__libc_start_main+0xf0]
  #4 [_init+0x2f61]
  #5 [<unknown>+0x2f61]
Test (null) failed.
**** DEBUG ****
(intel_gpu_top:25862) intel-mmio-CRITICAL: Test assertion failure function intel_mmio_use_pci_bar, file ../../lib/intel_mmio.c:145:
(intel_gpu_top:25862) intel-mmio-CRITICAL: Failed assertion: !(error != 0)
(intel_gpu_top:25862) intel-mmio-CRITICAL: Last errno: 13, Permission denied
(intel_gpu_top:25862) intel-mmio-CRITICAL: Couldn't map MMIO region
```

[This guy has the same problem.](https://www.dell.com/community/Linux-Developer-Systems/intel-gpu-top-critical-assertions/td-p/5096493)

Is this a bug? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this line in the output was key:

```
(intel_gpu_top:25862) intel-mmio-CRITICAL: Last errno: 13, Permission denied
```

Turns out that you need to run it as root:

```
sudo intel_gpu_top
```

It would be nice if they printed a "You must be root" message or something to the terminal instead of just crashing.....

Comment: I still get the same error even if I use `sudo`